Can Windows "Compress contents to save disk space" folder option yield PostgreSQL erratic behavior?
I'm maintaining an old PostgreSQL-based application (PostgreSQL 9.1.22) on a Windows 2012 Server and we have noticed some data integrity inconsistencies. No errors have been spotted in logs nor in the event viewer, but we have noticed that somebody (or Windows itself) has automatically set the "Compress contents to save disk space" option to the cluster directory (and its subdirectories). I understand that this option works at OS level so it shouldn't affect PostgreSQL (beyond some performance issues), but maybe I'm wrong. Does anybody know if this option might lead to data integrity issues?
Thank you.

Windows doesn't change compression settings so it's "someone". Databases have their own compression methods and don't like using file system compression. Even SQL Server only allows compressed folders for read-only filegroups and databases and warns for possible recovery failures

@ÁlvaroGonzález it's not broken, but neither is it meant for databases. Databases are essentially their own OSs, with their own file, thread, and CPU handling. File-system compression or deduplication interferes with that. every IT magazine that would be the SQL Server Magazine and yes, it did warn against that

NTFS compression was introduced in the 1990s so there's no reliability issue. Performance though will be worse because the database thinks it's writing 2 data or index pages and the OS ends up modifying 1, 2 or 3 actual pages, with half an index page in one block and half in another. In SQL Server's compression the database itself takes care of compressing data and buffering the compressed pages when needed.

Recover can be an issue even if you use dumps, because the database may try to preallocate X MBs but the actual allocated space may be a lot less. Without knowing what the final physical disk space will be, the database may start a restore or recovery even if there isn't enough space and fail after eating all available space. When that happens, all other databases on the server could crash as well

After a week with "Compress contents to save disk space" option disabled, I can confirm that this option causes data integrity problems with PostgreSQL engine 9.1.22 on Windows 2012 Server. So my advice is disabling it from the entire cluster directory and subdirectories.

Old, outdated software on (probably) old, outdated hardware is a great recipe for data corruption of all kinds. I wouldn't necessarily blame Windows, although it could of course be the source of the problem.

NTFS compression was introduced in NT 3.5.1, 18 years before Windows Server 2012 was released. As you said in dba.stackexchange.com though, the real problem will be performance. The database thinks it's writing 2 index pages while the OS end up writing half a page in one block and half in another without understanding anything about boundaries, row and page boundaries.
